# How to ensure atomicity in VxWorks structure operations?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, vxworks

I have written code involving multiple tasks, in VxWorks. They worked smoothly.

I didn't care about atomic operations, at that point in time. But later, while going through the literature, I found that atomic operations matter when multiple threads access same variable.

I had structures being used by more than one task and it worked fine. But from now on, I would like to be careful. So, are there any methods by which structure operations can be ensured to be atomically safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question is quite general.
You may manage concurrent access to resource (e.g. global variable) in following ways:

1. using semaphore; each task will "take" semaphore before doing something with that resource and "give" it afterwards, the binary semaphore is the best for this purpose
2. you may "lock" the task before doing something with that resource and "unlock" it afterwards, this way you make sure that the task will not be rescheduled and no other task can run until you unlock your task
3. for the case that the resource may be accessed from the interrupt handler (and so the N1 and N2 protection may not work) you may disable all interrupts before and enable them after.

The last way will always work, but if you will disable interrupts for long time the OS may stop working correctly (e.g. communication may fail on timeout).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are asking very general questions regarding the basic concerns/pitfals of multithreading.  To that effect, I would advise you to research a bit on the general topics of semaphores, mutexes, queues, etc.  This question might be a bit too general to answer in depth.

Regarding vxWorks specifically, there are many features of the OS that help you accomplish mutual exclusion or data passing between tasks.

I will refer you to semLib for semaphores and msgQLib for message queues (vxWorks documentation links below).

https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/vxworks_7_application_core_os_sr0630-enus/page/CORE/semLib.html
https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/vxworks_7_application_core_os_sr0630-enus/page/CORE/msgQLib.html

Happy coding!

Comment: my question is about atomicity while accessing Structures in Multitasking .I think that is pretty  much specific question .These links i have already seen long back.I think I am not finding the right audience for my questions .Some who have actually done stuff  like this on resource constrained platforms and faced the same issues .My bad :(

Comment: @achoora This has nothing to do with resource constrained platforms. The means to ensure "atomicity" as you call it is using semaphores.

Comment: The key is to create a shared semaphore (probably a mutex, but depends on the requirements) , and all tasks should take the semaphore before accessing structure, and release afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic means that operation will be executed without interruption.  So there should be no context switching while operation or set of operations are being executed. Mutex or semaphore cannot help in this case.  It is rarely needed, if your code is not low level you are probably OK.